# Effective technique for crossing high and dense mountain pine

Tags: backpacking

Is there any special effective technique (parkour or something similar) for crossing very high and dense mountain pine? Those ones can be really dense, and sometimes the only possibility to cross them is to walk on the top of them, and crossing it is usually very slow and tiring, especially with big backpack that likes to hook the branches.

[image]

I've seen some running technique in a documentary with Bear Grylls, but I've forgotten the name, and I know you can't believe everything you see in his films...

Comment: Qick half-answer. Usually in summer I carry a long staff instead of trekking poles. When going through dense brush, I use the staff to push nasties away from my face and hands, by holding the staff at an angle in front of my body.

Comment: How about snowshoes? :)

Answer (score 4):

There are ways to approach every mountain. The route that goes by ridges that are with sharper  slopes / drops can take you to the top exceedingly faster since the forest on such a ridge is relatively thinner as compared to the milder ascends of it. At the same time such a forest can be bushy or more-or-less thorny all the way.

Whereas, if you take a milder ascend, you may travel geographically more than a sharper ridge as I said earlier. On the other hand, such a route will allow you to run through dense forests as you should expect.

I personally prefer sharper ridges when I am climbing up a mountain and a milder ridge to get down as I can simply run through on a descend (though it is not advised to run while descending).

Now, if you just traversing a mountain and not actually getting on the top of it, then you may not have much of a choice. OR may be even if you intend to go from one mountain to another, you should take the milder ridge to ascend as you just might have exerted your knees and ultimately lower body while descending. Alas, its more about who is good with what!